# How can call a php custom function inside a <div>

Tags: php

I want call a php custom function(**writeMsg()**) inside a `<div>` tag.

Below is a code sample of how to do it, but I'm not too sure if this adheres to the syntax of the language?

```
 <?php
 function writeMsg() {
 echo "This is a test!";
 }
 echo "<div class='wrapper'>";
 for( $i=0; $i < 6; $i++ ) echo "<div>$i **call writeMsg()**</div>";
 echo "</div>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Like this way, `...echo "<div>$i ". writeMsg() . "</div>";`

Comment: It doesn't work,it doesn't write inside the divs.

Comment: Additing to what I said ^, instead of `echo` simply return the string, like this: `function writeMsg() { return "This is a test!"; }`. See @MarkB's answer.

Comment: What is your mean instead of echo?

Comment: Thanks,i could get the right answer,return instead of 'echo'.

Answer (score 4):

PHP is not recursively embeddable/executable.  You cannot embed PHP code inside a PHP string and expect PHP to execute it. Just do:

```
 echo "<div>" . writeMsg() . "</div>"
```

But note that your function is doing echo, which means it performs IMMEDIATELY output, and the above code sample will effectively execute as

```
writeMsg();
echo "<div></div>';
```

Your function should **RETURN** the string, not echo it.

Comment: Thanks,but i want that the output of function be inside div it is not .

Comment: Can you have a simple example?

Comment: you need an example of how to change your function from saying `echo` to saying `return`?

Answer (score 2):

First change your function to:

```
function writeMsg() {
   return "This is a test!";
}
```

And then just change your echo to:

```
 echo "<div>" . $i . " " . writeMsg(). "</div>";
```

Comment: The output of function doesn't appear inside <div> tag.

Comment: Just noticed you are echoing the string inside your function. You should be returning it. See my edit